# What is the TERM_PROGRAM and  TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION environment variables used for?

Tags: macos, terminal

After running:

```
env  ; #from with in terminal
```

I see the following output:

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal  ;#Not sure Terminal.app
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=273     ;#The CFBundleVersion of Terminal.app
TERM=xterm-color
SHELL=/bin/bash
...
```

After trying to put meaning to each of the variables listed I can't really find any definitive sources for what exactly the TERM_PROGRAM and TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION variables are used for. Man pages and Apropos are not showing anything explaining it, and Google is not as well. Clearly it is relating to some kind of Apple specific setting in Mac OS X, just not sure what?

Comment: This might be nothing more than an informational variable of the running terminal client to use in scripting for example. For example, it lists iTerm.app for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is just an environment variable that stores your default program that you want to use to bring up a terminal window.  There are several different applications on OS X that give you a Unix-like command prompt.  The default is the Apple-supplied terminal in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app.  If you've installed some other terminal like iTerm or AquaTerm, then this variable is likely set to that particular application, if it is your default.  The name `Apple_Terminal` must be some internal shortcut to the full /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app path.

Just like your `SHELL` variable, this is the default that is used in scripts or other programs, unless it is specified in those programs specifically, whereupon the default gets overwritten.

**EDIT**: actually [this answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7053241/1034317) seems to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but would you mind testing out your hypothesis in some way and update your answer with your findings?

Comment: Well, for example, @Gerry listed in the comment to the question that the `TERM_PROGRAM` variable listed iTerm.app for him.  If he can chime in and say whether or not that is his default terminal, that should be sufficient.  I don't know, off the top of my head a program that launches a terminal to test this - do you?

Comment: See the edit to the answer - it seems this has already been answered before on stack overflow.

Comment: To confirm: yes, `TERM_PROGRAM` is set to `Apple_Terminal` by Terminal to identify itself, and no other program should set it to that value. And `TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION` is the current version of the program identified with `TERM_PROGRAM`. You can use that, for example, to check whether Terminal is new enough to support some feature you want to use, like the escape sequences for setting the working directory and represented file (new in Lion).

Answer (score 4):

`TERM_PROGRAM` is used in `/etc/zshrc` and `/etc/bashrc` to run commands that are specific to the terminal program you are using when they open a shell.  By default, macOS supplies `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` and `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` which do some extra work to manage the current working directory and support suspending and resuming the terminal.  If you use another terminal program, you can place a file at `/etc/zshrc_$TERM_PROGRAM` or `/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM` and it will be executed when your terminal program opens a shell.  You have to ensure that your terminal program sets a value for `$TERM_PROGRAM` of course.

Answer (score 2):

Use Case:
I use iterm2, Apple_Terminal, and emacs vterm with zsh.

I put the below code in the theme setting section of  ~/.zshrc to use different zsh theme in each terminal

```
          ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
          if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = "Apple_Terminal" ]; then
              ZSH_THEME="afowler"
          elif [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = "iTerm.app" ]  &&  [ "$INSIDE_EMACS" = "vterm" ]; then
              ZSH_THEME="afowler"
          else
              ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
          fi
```